# Dynamically created form component by *ngFor is keeping value in form controls

Tags: angular, forms, templates, components, dynamically-generated

I am trying to generate forms dynamically inside mat-expansion-panel (and dialog to give the entire context). For now, I succeed to generate the new expansion panel and the form inside by using *ngFor loop. The problem is coming from 2 points:

- The form inside the expansion panel is coming from a component I coded
- The user is in charge to generate the new expansion panel and the form inside by clicking an "add" button

The final result is that everything works as expected but if the user start to fill some info inside a first form and decides to create a new form in the accordion, the newly created form get its form controls filled up with the data of the previous focused form :(

Here is a code example

Parent accordion

```html
(...)
<mat-step>            
    <ng-template matStepLabel>Ajouter des appartements</ng-template>           
    <button mat-raised-button (click)="addApartment()">Add</button>
    <mat-accordion multi="true">
        <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let apartment of apartments">
             <mat-expansion-panel-header>
                  <mat-panel-title>
                       {{apartment.title}}
                  </mat-panel-title>
                  <mat-panel-description>
                       {{apartment.description}}
                  </mat-panel-description>                
             </mat-expansion-panel-header>                
             <app-add-apartment-form [parentForm]="addLocationForm"></app-add-apartment-form>            
        </mat-expansion-panel>    
    </mat-accordion>            
</mat-step>
(...)
```

.ts file

```
(...)
addApartment(){
    this.apartments.push(new Apartment());
  }
(...)
```

Child component form (nothing fancy)

```html
<div [formGroup]="parentForm">
    <p>
        <mat-form-field formGroupName="apartmentDetails"> 
            <input matInput placeholder="Titre" formControlName="title" width="30%">
            <mat-error *ngIf="f.title.invalid">{{getTitleErrorMessage()}}</mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>
    </p>
    <p>
        <mat-form-field formGroupName="apartmentDetails">
            <textarea matInput placeholder="Description" formControlName="description" width="30%"></textarea>
            <mat-error *ngIf="f.description.invalid">{{getDescriptionErrorMessage()}}</mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>
    </p>
    <p>
        <mat-form-field formGroupName="apartmentDetails">
            <mat-label>Etage</mat-label>
            <mat-select width="30%" formControlName="floor">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let floor of floors" [value]="floor.value">
                    {{floor.viewValue}}
                </mat-option>
            </mat-select>            
            <mat-error *ngIf="f.floor.invalid">{{getFloorErrorMessage()}}</mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>
    </p>
(...)
```

Here are the result pictures :

First form fill https://i.stack.imgur.com/KC4y1.png

Add second form https://i.stack.imgur.com/OnnsJ.png

Thanks for your help !

Comment: 1.-create a form Array of formGroups, 2.-loop over the formArray controls, 3.-pass to your component the formArray.at(index) (or if iterate over *ngFor="grp of myArray.controls", simple use grp to feed your children component.)

Comment: Ok thank you. So I need to generate the form controls dynamically in my child component. Could u explain why I cannot use the html file template of my child component ? Why ngfor is duplicating values ?

Comment: see my answer -I beleave this is not necesary so form as you put in your code-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change a bit your form, but briefly, the elements that complete my comment are:

```
<form *ngIf="form" [formGroup]="form">
<mat-accordion>
  <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let grp of form.controls;let i=index" [formGroup]="grp">
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <mat-panel-title>
 <mat-panel-title>
                       {{grp.get('title').value}}
                  </mat-panel-title>
                  <mat-panel-description>
                       {{grp.get('description').value}}
                  </mat-panel-description> 
      </mat-panel-title>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <app-add-apartment-form [parentForm]="grp"></app-add-apartment-form>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
</form>
```

your form is

```
form=new FormArray([])
```

you has a function

```
createGroup()
{
   return new FormGroup({
     title:new FormControl()
     description:new FormControl()
     floor:new FormControl() 
   })
}
```

And your children

```
<div [formGroup]="parentForm">
<input formControlName="title">
<input formControlName="description">
<input formControlName="floor">
</div>
```

You has a function add that is

```
add()
{
  this.form.push(this.createGroup())
}
```